# Chunk time series dataset in N chunks for comparing means and variance

Tags: r, time-series

I 'm doing one project for analysing time series data. It's Apple stocks from 2018-1-1 to 2019-12-31. From the dataset, I selected two columns "Date" and "Ajd.close". I attached a small dataset here in below. (Alternatively: You can download the data directly from [Yahoo finance](https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?period1=1514764800&period2=1577836800&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true).  There is a download link under the blue button "Apply". )

I tested the dataset with adf.test(). It's not stationary. Now I would like to try another way, chunk the dataset into 24 periods(months), then compare the mean and variances of these chunked data.  I tried with chunker() but it seems did not work. How should I do it? Thank you!

Here is a shorter version of the dataset:

```
      Date       Adj.Close

1   2018-01-02    41.38024
2   2018-01-03    41.37303
3   2018-01-04    41.56522
4   2018-01-05    42.03845
5   2018-01-08    41.88231
6   2018-01-09    41.87751
7   2018-01-10    41.86789
8   2018-01-11    42.10571
9   2018-01-12    42.54050
10  2018-01-16    42.32431
11  2018-01-17    43.02335
12  2018-01-18    43.06179
13  2018-01-19    42.86961
14  2018-01-22    42.51889
15  2018-01-23    42.52850
16  2018-01-24    41.85107
17  2018-01-25    41.10399
18  2018-01-26    41.20008
19  2018-01-29    40.34730
20  2018-01-30    40.10948
21  2018-01-31    40.21999
22  2018-02-01    40.30407
23  2018-02-02    38.55526
24  2018-02-05    37.59198
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `split` the dataset and use `map` to make calculations on every chunck :

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17533, 17534, 17535, 17536, 
                                  17539, 17540, 17541, 17542, 17543, 17547, 17548, 17549, 17550, 
                                  17553, 17554, 17555, 17556, 17557, 17560, 17561, 17562, 17563, 
                                  17564, 17567), class = "Date"), Adj.Close = c(41.38024, 41.37303, 
                                                                                41.56522, 42.03845, 41.88231, 41.87751, 41.86789, 42.10571, 42.5405, 
                                                                                42.32431, 43.02335, 43.06179, 42.86961, 42.51889, 42.5285, 41.85107, 
                                                                                41.10399, 41.20008, 40.3473, 40.10948, 40.21999, 40.30407, 38.55526, 
                                                                                37.59198)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
                                                                                                          "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
                                                                                                          "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"), class = "data.frame")

# As an example : split every 10 rows
df %>% split((seq(nrow(df))-1) %/% 10) %>% 
       map(~{list(startDate = min(.x$Date),
                  avg = mean(.x$Adj.Close),
                  sd = sd(.x$Adj.Close))}) %>% bind_rows
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   startDate    avg    sd
#>   <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 2018-01-02  41.9 0.382
#> 2 2018-01-17  41.9 1.11 
#> 3 2018-01-31  39.2 1.32
```

Comment: I think I got it. Those were date sequence, right?

Comment: Exactly : these are the dates from your example (R counts from `1970-01-01` on)

Comment: :D , got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We can also do this with `group_by/summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), 10, n()))) %>% 
   summarise(startDate = min(Date), 
             avg = mean(Adj.Close), sd = sd(Adj.Close), .groups = 'drop') %>%
   select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  startDate    avg    sd
#  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
#1 2018-01-02  41.9 0.382
#2 2018-01-17  41.9 1.11 
#3 2018-01-31  39.2 1.32
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17533, 17534, 17535, 17536, 
17539, 17540, 17541, 17542, 17543, 17547, 17548, 17549, 17550, 
17553, 17554, 17555, 17556, 17557, 17560, 17561, 17562, 17563, 
17564, 17567), class = "Date"), Adj.Close = c(41.38024, 41.37303, 
41.56522, 42.03845, 41.88231, 41.87751, 41.86789, 42.10571, 42.5405, 
42.32431, 43.02335, 43.06179, 42.86961, 42.51889, 42.5285, 41.85107, 
41.10399, 41.20008, 40.3473, 40.10948, 40.21999, 40.30407, 38.55526, 
37.59198)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
"19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank @akrun. I just came back. When I take a deep look at Waldi and yours answer, I understand it's split based on 10 days. So I suppose if I want to split in month, it needs to divide by 30. However, is there some other way that we can divide the dataset based on month or quarter, etc. Both of your answers are excellent.  If I ask too much, please just ignore then :)

Comment: Thanks @akrun for your supplemented answer :)

Comment: you mean how to split dataset in month or quarter? Sure I will do it. One minutes, doing

Comment: I added it @akrun

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to check the stationarity of *returns* as opposed to raw prices.  Using the data in the Note at the end convert it to zoo class, calculate the returns, aggregate it by year/month computing mean and sd statistics and plot.  If you prefer year/quarter replace `as.yearmon` with `as.yearqtr`.

```
library(zoo)

aapl <- read.zoo(aapl.df)
aapl.ret <- diff(aapl, arith = FALSE) - 1

stats <- function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x))
aapl.ret.stats <- aggregate(aapl.ret, as.yearmon, stats)

plot(aapl.ret.stats, main = "AAPL Adj Returns")
```

To use a chunk of arbitrary length, here 10, we can use rollapplyr:

```
na.omit(rollapplyr(drop(aapl.ad.ret), 10, by = 10, stats))
```

### Yahoo data

There isn't enough data in the question to really show the above but using quantmod we can download a longer series and perform the same operations giving the plot shown at after the code.  We also show some tests that could be run with the data.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")

aapl.ad <- Ad(AAPL)
aapl.ad.ret <- diff(aapl.ad, arith = FALSE) - 1

stats <- function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x))
aapl.ret.stats <- aggregate(aapl.ad.ret, as.yearmon, stats)

# plot shown after code
plot(aapl.ret.stats, main = "AAPL Adj Returns")

# some additional things to try -- output not shown

aapl.ad.ret.na <- na.omit(aapl.ad.ret)
acf(aapl.ad.ret.na)
Box.test(aapl.ad.ret.na)

library(tseries)
adf.test(aapl.ad.ret.na)
kpss.test(aapl.ad.ret.na, null = "Level")
kpss.test(aapl.ad.ret.na, null = "Trend")
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "      Date       Adj.Close
1   2018-01-02    41.38024
2   2018-01-03    41.37303
3   2018-01-04    41.56522
4   2018-01-05    42.03845
5   2018-01-08    41.88231
6   2018-01-09    41.87751
7   2018-01-10    41.86789
8   2018-01-11    42.10571
9   2018-01-12    42.54050
10  2018-01-16    42.32431
11  2018-01-17    43.02335
12  2018-01-18    43.06179
13  2018-01-19    42.86961
14  2018-01-22    42.51889
15  2018-01-23    42.52850
16  2018-01-24    41.85107
17  2018-01-25    41.10399
18  2018-01-26    41.20008
19  2018-01-29    40.34730
20  2018-01-30    40.10948
21  2018-01-31    40.21999
22  2018-02-01    40.30407
23  2018-02-02    38.55526
24  2018-02-05    37.59198"
aapl.df <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Comment: Hi @G.Grothendieck, thanks for the answer. Just saw it. Compared the other two excellent answers I got, I think your answer is more suitable for this use case. Thank you!